# Installing django-autocomplete (not light!) on osx

Tags: python, django, macos, autocomplete, pip

When I'm trying to install `django-autocomplete` from requirements:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements/requirements.txt
```

or without sudo:

```
pip install -r requirements/requirements.txt
```

or using `pip` directly:

```
pip install django-autocomplete
```

or with sudo:

```
sudo pip install django-autocomplete
```

it fails with error message:

```
Collecting django-autocomplete (from -r requirements/requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading django-autocomplete-v0.1.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-NHKHH9/django-autocomplete/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 18, in <module>

    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-NHKHH9/django-autocomplete/setup.py'
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem? I'm using newest OSX (yosemite).

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on osx. But this issue only occurs with the `0.1` version, not the `0.2`. So `pip install django-autocomplete==0.2` works fine here.

Comment: Thanks, but after I've tried I've got an error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-autocomplete==0.2 (from versions: 0.1`

Comment: Upstream development stalled in 2011. It probably never got ported to python3. For me it appears to work in `python2.x`, I see the same error in `python3.x`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error under Ubuntu 16.04.
Try with the python module django-autocomplete-light:

```
sudo pip install django-autocomplete-light
```

It solved the problem in my case.